# Radiobutton clicked,

Tags: java, android

I added radiobuttons to my radiogroup, I want to add an attribute to the buttons so when one of the added buttons is clicked a method gets called. How do I do that, I tried searching but I didnt find my answer. I have a for loop to add the radiobuttons

```
enter code here

RadioGroup group = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup);
RadioButton button;
String accounts= msg.getData().getString("text");
String[] SepAccounts= accounts.split(":");
    for (int i=0; i<SepAccounts.length;i++)
        SepAccounts[i]= SepAccounts[i].replaceAll("-"," ");
    Context context= group.getContext(); 

    for (int i=0; i < SepAccounts.length; i++){ 
            button = new RadioButton(context);
            button.setText(SepAccounts[i]);
        group.addView(button);
    }
```

This is part of my code where I add the radio buttons

and this is where I create my radio group

```
<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_below="@id/NFCHeaderTextView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/RadioGroup"
    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked">

</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: What have to done so far? please add some code

Comment: What framework are you using? There is like no information in your question?!

Comment: You tried searching you say? [I highly doubt that](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html#HandlingEvents)

Comment: Ya I found that site, but they are doing it in a different way, they already know how many buttons are in the radio group but I do not, I am adding radio buttons from a server

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
radioButton.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Your listener will need to implement OnClickListener.

Answer (score 1):

Add an OnClickListener to each button before you add it to the group...

```
    RadioGroup group = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup);
    RadioButton button;
    String accounts = msg.getData().getString("text");
    String[] SepAccounts = accounts.split(":");
    for (int i = 0; i < SepAccounts.length; i++)
        SepAccounts[i] = SepAccounts[i].replaceAll("-", " ");
    Context context = group.getContext();

    for (int i = 0; i < SepAccounts.length; i++) {
        button = new RadioButton(context);
        button.setText(SepAccounts[i]);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                doStuff(v);
            }
        });
        group.addView(button);
    }

...

private void doStuff(View v)
{
    // radio button "v" was clicked
}
```

Take a look at the documentation for more information about the OnClickListener http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html

Comment: You need to use :

`View.OnClickListener`

Comment: I really appreciate it, I have been working on this since 9am... thankss